# assert message box is not clickable and not focusable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, assert

I have been working on a C++ project in VS2012. All was fine and suddenly assert messages stopped working. Whenever an assert fires and a message box shows up, it's not clickable. If I click around and the windows goes to background, I can't bring it to foreground by clicking its button in taskbar. If I manage to see the assert message window afterwards, it's filled with plain white, no text or buttons.

Of course, if I start a new project and try assert there - everything's fine.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Your program is broken.  Badly.  It can't even keep a message box alive.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you familiar with this symptom? Is it a problem with event loop in my program?